# How to add java script and css style files to wix site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

adding HTML code is easy.  in wix: click on the + Add > Embed Code > Embed HTML. and you can type a code in a small window or paste some HTML code.

but what if I wrote some code on visual studio code and I have 3 files: index.html, app.js, and style.css and I want to add the files app.js and style.css also to my Wix site?

I saw the public & backend areas in the Wix editor and i can create in the public some files like app.js or style.css but how do I use then these files with my HTML code or with my site?
I tried to read some tutorials on the Wix site and some youtube tutorials but it seems to be too complicated.

this is the HTML code in the visual studio code software:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Google Maps Api</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">

</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap&v=weekly&language=he"
      defer
    ></script>

<script src="/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

so i copied this code of the HTML to my Wix site embed HTML code. but it's not showing the google map like in visual studio code. so i guess that maybe i need to add somehow also the style.css code and the app.js code too.

the app.js code in visual studio code:

```
let map;

function initMap() {
    // The location of Uluru
    const uluru = { lat: 32.1582615544072, lng: 34.89155037133181 };

    // The map, centered at Uluru
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: uluru,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      fullscreenControl: true,
    });

    /*const myLatlng = { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 };
    // Create the initial InfoWindow.
  let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Click the map to get Lat/Lng!",
    position: myLatlng,
  });

  infoWindow.open(map);
  // Configure the click listener.
  map.addListener("mousemove", (mapsMouseEvent) => {
    // Close the current InfoWindow.
    infoWindow.close();
    // Create a new InfoWindow.
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      position: mapsMouseEvent.latLng,
    });
    infoWindow.setContent(
      JSON.stringify(mapsMouseEvent.latLng.toJSON(), null, 2)
    );
    infoWindow.open(map);
  });*/

    // Create the DIV to hold the control.
  const centerControlDiv = document.createElement("div");
  // Create the control.
  const centerControl = createCenterControl(map);
  // Append the control to the DIV.
  centerControlDiv.appendChild(centerControl);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(centerControlDiv);

    const chicago = { lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 };

    /**
     * Creates a control that recenters the map on Chicago.
     */
    function createCenterControl(map) {
      const controlButton = document.createElement("button");
    
      // Set CSS for the control.
      controlButton.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
      controlButton.style.border = "2px solid #fff";
      controlButton.style.borderRadius = "3px";
      controlButton.style.boxShadow = "0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)";
      controlButton.style.color = "rgb(25,25,25)";
      controlButton.style.cursor = "pointer";
      controlButton.style.fontFamily = "Roboto,Arial,sans-serif";
      controlButton.style.fontSize = "16px";
      controlButton.style.lineHeight = "28px";
      controlButton.style.borderLeftWidth = "8px";
      controlButton.style.margin = "8px 8px 22px 0";
      controlButton.style.padding = "0 5px";
      controlButton.style.textAlign = "center";
      controlButton.textContent = "Center Map";
      controlButton.title = "Click to recenter the map";
      controlButton.type = "button";
      
      // Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to Chicago.
      controlButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        map.setCenter(chicago);
      });
      return controlButton;
    }

    const rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map,
        bounds: {
            north: uluru.lat - 0.005,
            south: uluru.lat + 0.005,
            west: uluru.lng - 0.005,
            east: uluru.lng + 0.005,
        },
      });
}

  window.initMap = initMap;
```

and the style.css code in visual studio code:

```
#map
{
    width: 1500px;
    height:900px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

#map.fullscreen {
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

how can I integrate what I did in visual studio code with the wix?

Comment: You can add your JS code inside a `<script>` tag along with your HTML code.

Comment: @PrerakSola it's working. but why in the visual studio code software when running the index.html with live server when it's loading the google map using my api i can change the zoom in/out with the mouse wheel but in my wix site i need to press also the control key with the mouse wheel to zoom in out ? is there a way to remove/cancel/avoid from the control key press ?